# Can't install a managed package because some components from the package are already present in a sandbox

Tags: managed-package

The bottom line is:

- a sandbox that does not have a managed package installed
- some flexi pages with the namespace from the managed package are present in the sandbox
- half of an Apex trigger on a non existing Qwertyuiop__e object with non existing Apex class. 11 lines of code. The 11th line `} else if (record.asdf__c == 'someTe`. This trigger is non accessible from UI. VSCode downloads this half trigger.
- its Production org has the managed package installed.
- other sandboxes are good

Anybody saw such kind of magic before? What caused it?

My course of action is to just refresh the sanbox. However, I would like to preserv this artifact intact :-) Unusable but unique :-)

Comment: You can use `sfdx force source retrieve` to copy what is in the Sandbox to your laptop before the refresh.

Comment: Yes, but it does not explain what happened. I'm curious on what happened or how it is possible at all.